# Dealing with non positive definite matrix covariance (possible numeric issue)

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, covariance, skew-normal-distribution

I'm generating random number of a multivariate skew normal distribution. Here is my code:

```
rsmn = function(Xi, Omega, delta){
  n = dim(Omega)[1]
  Omega.barra = cov2cor(Omega)
  omega = diag(sqrt(diag(Omega)))
  delta = rep(delta, n)
  D_delta = (diag(n)-diag(delta^2))^(1/2)
  inv.D_delta =  solve(D_delta)
  Phi = inv.D_delta%*%(Omega.barra - delta%*%t(delta))%*%inv.D_delta
 # U0 = t(rmvn(1, mu = rep(0,n), sigma=Phi))
  U0 = mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = rep(0,n), Sigma = Phi)
  Z =D_delta%*%U0 + delta*abs(rnorm(1))
  Y = t(Xi + omega%*%Z)
  return(Y)
}
```

When I use a small dimension (n=2), everything works well, but if I use larger dimension, I get the following error in `U0`:

```
Error in mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = rep(0, n), Sigma = Phi) : 


'Sigma' is not positive definite
```

I'm using `delta = .9; Xi = 0`, and here is my covariance function:

```
> Omega
        1       2         3       4       5         6
1 1.00000 0.95896 0.0222424 0.72844 0.98414 0.3259422
2 0.95896 1.00000 0.0413895 0.84197 0.95657 0.2235418
3 0.02224 0.04139 1.0000000 0.11505 0.02183 0.0002127
4 0.72844 0.84197 0.1150523 1.00000 0.69446 0.0856466
5 0.98414 0.95657 0.0218348 0.69446 1.00000 0.3336316
6 0.32594 0.22354 0.0002127 0.08565 0.33363 1.0000000
```

Any hint on how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: You are a brave soul to use Omega and omega in the same patch of code. The problem here is the few very large correlations. Values of 0.98 and above will not be distinguishable from 1.00 except at very large sample sizes. How you solve the problem depends on why those values are there in the first place.

Comment: It looks like (at least one version of) [mvrnorm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-0/topics/mvrnorm) has a `tol` parameter to allow for a numerically positive-*semi*-definite covariance matrix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative sigma Multivariate variate normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422459/negative-sigma-multivariate-variate-normal-distribution)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 it's worked when I increase the `tol` value. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @EdRigdon, I cannot remove these values. My covariance depends on the distance from certain points and I cannot discard those points nearby.

Comment: Then it looks like you face the oldest trade-off in statistics, between accuracy and precision. Ridge or other biased estimation methods may let you skirt the collinearity problem. Possibly, depending on the structure of your model, limited information estimation methods may get you better estimates at the cost of less statistical efficiency.